# Managing the back stack after oauth login on Android

Tags: android, oauth, back-stack

I am implementing oauth login in Android, and I'm stuck on one point.  I am required to redirect to the native browser to initiate the login (rather than use an embedded WebView of my own), but that is causing issues with the back stack.  My goal is simple: return to my activity after the redirect with no trace of the native browser in the back stack.  Here is the closest I've come so far:

To initiate the login from my activity I use:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

I have a separate activity to receive the return redirect and handle the rest of the login process.  I don't really care whether it's a separate activity or not, it is just my current solution.  In its manifest I set `android:noHistory="true"`.  Once it finishes the login process, I *attempt* to return to the first activity using code like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, OrigActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

However, this ends up creating a second copy of the original activity, and when I press back it returns me to the first copy.  In other words, it does not seem to respect `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`.  Did I miss something simple to make it work, despite all my searching?  Or is there some other way I should go about all of this?

**Edit:** It turns out the problem stems from the fact that the browser is launched in a separate task. From some Android documentation:

> ... if your application issues an intent to open the Android Browser, its activity is not placed in the same task as your application. Instead, either a new task starts for the Browser or, if the Browser already has a task running in the background, that task is brought forward to handle the new intent.

If I set my original activity's launch mode to `singleTask` it properly brings it to the foreground instead of creating a new copy, but a new problem occurs.  The browser is now in the back stack behind all of my activities, so now it seems `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` is not being respected.  I'm not sure if that brings me any closer to a proper solution ...

**Edit 2:** Correction: if the browser was not running before I launched it, everything works perfectly.  However, if it WAS already running `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` seems to have no effect on it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing makes sense because calling the browser with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY wouldn't remove back stack from PRIOR to the start of your application.